# IPv6 Forwarding between interfaces

Tags: ipv6

I am attempting to simulate an ipv6 wan (on an airgapped network). I have a CentOS 6 machine in the middle with eth1 and eth2 each pointing to an ipv6 network (call them "north" and "south").

North machines can see the north interface on the router, and south machines can see the south interface on the router, but north machines cannot see south machines.

The router is running radvd. Machines on north and south get router advertisements correctly.

Everything in /proc is set to forward: net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding, all.forwarding, eth1.forwarding, eth2.forwarding. (via sysctl.conf at boot)

Lastly, this configuration exactly mirrors a similar setup - however the existing one uses Ubuntu (kernel 3.8.x vs Centos 2.6.x). But otherwise, it's the same networks and same configuration.

the output of `ip -f inet6 route` looks like this:

```
fdd0:1::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fdd0:1::/64 dev eth1  metric 1024  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fdd0:2::/64 dev eth2  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fdd0:2::/64 dev eth2  metric 1024  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
```

On our Ubuntu version,

```
fdd0:1::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
fdd0:2::/64 dev eth2  proto kernel  metric 256
```

(Note the lack of doubled entries)

How drastically would Unbuntu and CentOS (based on kernel) differ? Why does CentOS double entries?

Comment: How _exactly_ did you configure this CentOS machine?

Comment: I don't think the differences between the routing table entries could explain a complete lack of connectivity. A packet capture on each side of the router to see exactly how far the packets get, should provide some clues.